# how to install python and machine learning libraries offline in windows 10?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, shared-libraries

i am trying to install opencv .i downloaded  "opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar" and extracted it after that copy the file in a system that hv no internet . i run the conda install PATH_TO_FILE/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar through conda prompt....
but it is not helping & showing "http error"
how to import libraries offline?

Comment: Where did you download the package from?

Answer (score 0):

Try unzipping  the file, then open a terminal on that directory, run- **pip install your-unzipped-folder/filename**.
you can also use wheel- before the previous command- run - **pip install wheel**- first.

Comment: pip is not present as its installation also requires internet any other alternative ?